# Adding Layout file in Android studio hides the dialog box

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to add Layout file in Android studio in my windows computer new-> xml-> Layout XML file. But the dialog box was bigger than my screen that I wasn't able to minimize it vertically so I can click finish. All the buttons like, cancel, Finish... were hidden behind my task bar. I worked around that by adding a resource file in my layout folder but I wanted to know if there is a setting to change that behavior.[image: All buttons hidden behind the task bar]

Comment: You couldn't just drag the window until you could see it or drag the corner of the window to resize it? The next time you use it it should be in the same position/size when you left it.

Comment: I can minimize it horizontally but not vertically. I could only drag it upwards but not far enough so that I can see the buttons.

Comment: I mean, it looks like you should be able to get either the top left or right corner, and drag it into itself to make it smaller and then grab the whole window and drag it up.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird. However you can do a tricky thing! :)

In your windows toolbar at the bottom, right click on a blank space, then you will have many options like:

- Cascade windows
- Show windows stacked
- Show windows side by side

This will arrange all your windows. Try them.